# Lock page when it's already opened

Tags: javascript, php, locking, handler, tracking

I am developing an easy cms to internal use. Via this cms, the user can create and edit some product's page. I'd like to alert the user that try to edit a specific product's page already opened by another user.

I'm using the following script, but i don't know how to easy alert the second user, something like "ehi, this page is editing by another user", click on "ok" button and redirect him to homepage.

**I track all info correctly**, just i don't know how to alert the second user and lock page for him.

Thanks in advance!

**product's page**

```
<script src="pages/includes/jsHandler.js"></script>
  <script>
  window.onload = function(){ return start('<?php echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); ?>');};
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){  return end(); };
  window.onclose = function(){ return end(); };
</script>
```

**jsHandler.js**

```
  function start(pageName) {
    var xmlhttp3;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
      xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
        }
      }
      xmlhttp3.open("GET","pages/includes/trackStart.php?pageName="+pageName,true);
      xmlhttp3.send();
    }

    function end() {
        var xmlhttp3;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
      xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
        }
      }
        xmlhttp3.open("GET","pages/includes/trackEnd.php",true);
        xmlhttp3.send();
    }
```

**trackStart.php**

```
<?php session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
require("dbHandler.php");
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['startTime'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$_SESSION['pageName'] = $_GET['pageName'];

if(isset($_SESSION['pageViews']))
{
    $_SESSION['pageViews'] = $_SESSION['pageViews'] + 1;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['pageViews'] = 0;
}

$ip = $_SESSION['ip'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
$user_location = $details->city . " , " . $details->country;

saveData($_SESSION['ip'],$_SESSION['startTime'],'0',$_SESSION['pageName'],$_SESSION['pageViews'],'0','start',$user_location);
?>
```

**trackEnd.php**

```
<?php session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
require("dbHandler.php");
$_SESSION['endTime'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$timeSpent = $_SESSION['endTime'] - $_SESSION['startTime'];
$timeSpent = $timeSpent . " seconds";

saveData($_SESSION['ip'],$_SESSION['startTime'],$_SESSION['endTime'],$_SESSION['pageName'],$_SESSION['pageViews'],$timeSpent,'end');
?>
```

**dbHandler.php**

```
<?php
function saveData($ip,$startTime,$endTime,$pageName,$viewCount,$timeSpent,$action,$location)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "blabla", "blabla", "blabla");

    if($action == 'start')
    {

        $q = "INSERT INTO track_user(ip_address,start_time,end_time,page_name,view_count,time_spent,user_location) VALUES('$ip','$startTime','$endTime','$pageName','$viewCount','$timeSpent','$location')";
    $mysqli->query($q);

    }
    else
    {
        $q = "UPDATE track_user SET end_time = '$endTime', time_spent = '$timeSpent' WHERE ip_address = '$ip' AND start_time = '$startTime' AND page_name = '$pageName'";
    $mysqli->query($q);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to prevent them opening this page in the first place if it is being edited already? Otherwise it's not clear what specific problem you have is

Comment: For example Wordpress alerts you when you try to edit a post that another user is being edit in that specific moment. Just an alert to advise the second user that the page is already open by another person. In this way the page can't be edit by 2 or more people at the same time, but the first user has to save his modify to permit the second user to edit that page :)

Comment: so if it's just for visual create a semi transparent overlay and include that in page if your `editMode` conditions are met

Comment: editMode? A condition it could be "pageName of first user is X and end_start is 0, if the pageName of second user is X, then show alert to second user that say page is already opened by first user"

Comment: i don't know what exactly you are tracking.... so I simply called it `editMode` which would be a Boolean based on your db lookup for that page

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie :( i don't know how to communicate with my js to alert when the boolean or another condition is valid. I've tried https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ but it's not return anything...

Comment: charlietfl, solved! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I made a php api that select the current pageName. If pageName is equal and end_time = 0, means that page is already opened and i set $risultato = 1. In my html, i used this code to alert the user (Boostrap modal):

```
<script>
  $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="session-locked" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">'+
                     '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
                         '<div class="modal-content">'+
                             '<div class="modal-header bg-primary">'+
                                 '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icons-office-52"></i></button>'+
                                 '<h4 class="modal-title">Scheda occupata</h4>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                 '<p><br />La scheda è occupata da un altro utente.<br />Clicca OK per tornare in Homepage</p>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                 '<button id="idle-locked-dialog-keepalive" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>'+
                             '</div>'+
                         '</div>'+
                     '</div>'+
                   '</div>');
  var page = '<?php echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); ?>';
  var time = '<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']); ?>';
      var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: api_ricerca_lock, type: "GET",dataType: "json", data: {pageName: page, startTime: time}} )
      .done(function(json) {
        if (json.risultato == 1) {
          $('#session-locked').modal('show');
          $('#idle-locked-dialog-keepalive').on('click', function () {
              $('#session-locked').modal('hide');
              window.location = "main.php";
          });
        }
        else {
          window.onload = function(){ return start('<?php echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); ?>');};
          window.onbeforeunload = function(){  return end(); };
          window.onclose = function(){ return end(); };
        }
      })
      .fail(function(response) {
        alert( "error" );
      });
</script>
```